# I keep receiving "NameError: name 'username' is not defined" error

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

I'm having immense trouble logging into an online account via python 2.7.11. I've spent many hours trying to figure it out, and going through my short code over and over again. If anybody could please help me with this, I will be you humble servant.

My code is:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "https://www.matchbook.com/bpapi/rest/security/session/"
    login_data = {
        username: "Marcel",
        password: "*******"
    }
    c.post(url,data = login_data)
    page = c.get("https://www.matchbook.com/bpapi/rest/security/session/")
    print page.content
```

to which I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
```

I have also tried defining the username and password variables as variables and putting the username and password key's in inverted commas in the dictionary.

To which I get the response:

```
<Response [415]>
{"errors":[{"messages":["Please login to continue"]}]}
```

Any help, please!

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant:

```
login_data = {
    "username": "Marcel",
    "password": "*******"
}
```

What you have is trying to look up a variable `username` and use it's value as the key.  Since you don't have a `username` variable, you get the `NameError`.

Comment: Jup, I have done that! That is the second part of my question :)

Comment: @MarcelHattingh -- Generally you need to use some part of the login response in the next requests.  I don't know the particular API, but it _usually_ involves setting some header (or possibly cookie -- though `requests.Session` _might_ handle that for you...) with a value that can be retrieved from the initial login response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but Alex's response below worked. So it doesn't seem like I need headers or cookies! Thanks a lot tho, too! :)

Comment: @MarcelHattingh -- It's probably using cookies and the Session is taking care of it for you.  You should probably accept his answer if it is what helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `c.post(url,data = login_data)` change `data` to `json` as the data needs to be JSON encoded and the way you've done it is form encoded.

For older versions of `requests`, use `data = json.dumps(login_data)`.

Comment: Whattttttt, it worked. Alex Hall. You did not make my day. You made my week. Hope you have the best day :)